# DeSerializing JSON returns null value C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, deserialization, json-deserialization

I want to deserialize the data which is coming from an API request, but when I try to deserialize, it always returns null values.

Here is the JSON data:

```
{
  "Meta Data": {
    "1. Information": "FX Intraday (1min) Time Series",
    "2. From Symbol": "USD",
    "3. To Symbol": "EUR",
    "4. Last Refreshed": "2019-04-19 09:19:00",
    "5. Interval": "1min",
    "6. Output Size": "Compact",
    "7. Time Zone": "UTC"
  },
  "Time Series FX (1min)": {
    "2019-04-19 09:19:00": {
      "1. open": "0.8890",
      "2. high": "0.8890",
      "3. low": "0.8890",
      "4. close": "0.8890"
    },
    "2019-04-19 09:18:00": {
      "1. open": "0.8890",
      "2. high": "0.8890",
      "3. low": "0.8890",
      "4. close": "0.8890"
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the way I tried to convert it:

```
public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("Meta Data")]
    public MetaData MetaData { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Time Series FX (1min)")]
    public TimeSeries TimeSeries { get; set; }
}

public class MetaData
{
    [JsonProperty("1. Information")]
    public string Information { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2. From Symbol")]
    public string FromSymbol { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("3. To Symbol")]
    public string ToSymbol { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("4. Last Refreshed")]
    public string LastRefreshed { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("5. Interval")]
    public string Interval { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("6. Output Size")]
    public string OutputSize { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("7. Time Zone")]
    public string TimeZone { get; set; }
}

public class TimeSeries
{
    public List<Time> Times { get; set; }
}

public class Time 
{
    [JsonProperty("1. open")]
    public decimal Open { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("2. high")]
    public decimal High { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("3. low")]
    public decimal Low { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("4. close")]
    public decimal Close { get; set; }
}
```

Now after updating with numbers, meta data is coming with appropriate values, but `TimeSeries` always gives me a null value. I doubt I have the model right so please take a look at that.  Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I think it may be as you have the key in JSON as "1. Information" but in your C# class it's called "Information". Are the keys returned from the API request something you can control or is that fixed?

Comment: does exactly the json returned by your api ???

Comment: I think that your JSON is not well formatted

Comment: yes api returing me the well formated data i checked it with online convertors

Comment: You need to use a `Dictionary<string, Time>` for the `TimeSeries` property, not a `TimeSeries` class containing a `List<Time>`.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54375172/10263) to see how.  I'm going to mark this question as a duplicate.

Comment: it`s not working mate Lhocv retuns the null value

Comment: @UdayTeja [Works fine for me.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8dpAcn)

Comment: Thankyou it worked there is small issue with the model now its working thankyou @Brain Rogers

Answer (score 4):

Remove the digits from the JSON identifier. 
JSON.Net cannot find the properties if they're not exactly as written within the source code.

E.g.:

```
{ "Information": "myInfo" }
```

Instead of:

```
{ "1. Information": "myInfo" }
```

Comment: Update the question please go throuh it

Answer (score 3):

As SimonC says the JSON data is not matching with what you have in the class. If the return from the API is fixed then you want:

```
[JsonProperty("1. Information")]
public string Information { get; set; }
```

not

```
[JsonProperty("Information")]
public string Information { get; set; }
```

With similar changes to the `JsonProperty` attribute for all the other properties in the class

Comment: Update the question please go throuh it

Answer (score 1):

Change your `[JsonProperty("Information")]
    public string Information { get; set; }` to  `[JsonProperty("1. Information")]
    public string Information { get; set; }` in your `public class MetaData`
    To be honest, you should change all the `public class MetaData` objects in such way!

Comment: Update the question please go throuh it

Comment: So, may I know what exactly do you use for parse.convert JSON?
Is it Newtonsoft.Json?

Comment: there is small issue with the model now its working thankyou